# Can you declare a variable inside an array?

Tags: typescript

I want to create an array of the week with each one being of my "work hours" class.

When I try to declare them inside of the array, I get an error and when looking at the JS file I see the array is translated to `const week = [let, sunday = new WorkHours,`

Is there a way around this?

```
class WorkHours {
    day: string;
    night: string;
}

    let sunday = new WorkHours;
    let monday = new WorkHours;
    let tuesday = new WorkHours;
    let wednesday = new WorkHours;
    let thursday = new WorkHours;
    let friday = new WorkHours;
    let saturday = new WorkHours;

const week = [
    sunday,
    monday,
    tuesday,
    wednesday,
    thursday,
    friday,
    saturday,
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare variables inside arrays. You can shrink what you've got a bit by using destructuring:

```
class WorkHours {
    day: string
    night: string
}

const week = [new WorkHours(), new WorkHours(), new WorkHours(), new WorkHours(), new WorkHours(), new WorkHours(), new WorkHours()]

const [sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday ] = week
```